# How do I get the difference between a mysql timestamp and the php current time?

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

The question i guess is kind of 2 questions:

1. How do i even GET the current time in php and in a format that is easily compared to and
2. Once i have that, i have a mysql timestamp in this format, 2011-06-30 04:33:00 , that I need to be compared to the php current time.

thank you so so much in advance, 
Binny

Comment: Are you needing the difference in your MySQL query or is this needed in your PHP processing after the query has run?

Comment: php processing after the query ran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime($query_result['timestamp'])`

This will convert your MySQL timestamp value to the correct seconds since Jan 1, 1970 value. Then it's just a matter of subtracting the two to get the difference.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're storing it as a `DATETIME` column.  As such, in MySQL

```
SELECT
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_column`) AS `timestamp`,
    ...
FROM
    ...
```

Then, in PHP:

```
$time_diff_in_seconds = time() - $query_result['timestamp']
```

However, I'd just let the database do it:

```
SELECT
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `date_column`)) AS time_diff,
    ...
FROM
    ...
```

Comment: I'm actually storing it as a TIMESTAMP column

Comment: @bzupnick: PHP timestamps and MySQL unix timestamps are identical - seconds since Jan 1/1970. No processing is required unless timezones/daylight savings details get involved.

Comment: but the timestamp gives me  2011-06-30 04:33:00 and the php timestamp gives me a bunch of numbers....im guessing milliescond....but theyre not the same format

Comment: ok, fine, i did what you said, and got this: 1309280266, how do i format that into hours, minuetes, etc?

Comment: OK, so that's basically now, which means your MySQL value probably came back as zero.  Check the second example.

Comment: Just saw your comment, why can't the database do the heavy lifting on this one?

Comment: Well, in my second example I let the database calculate the difference (which is in seconds, by the way) so that all PHP has to do is convert it to a format it likes.  Alternatively, you could remove the `TIME_TO_SEC` call and you'd get a string that was 'HH:MM:SS' where 'HH' can be any number.  So, why not let the database do it so that when the data gets to you, it's already processed?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should check:  are the two times coming from the same machine?  If they are coming from different machines, you should worry about time zones and synchronization.